# deleting array elements constructed with placement new

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, placement-new

I was looking into the case when we create a dynamic array of class types. As I know there isn't a method to create the array while calling a non-default constructor of the class directly. One way to so is initializing the array with normally and then looping and calling the non-default constructor for each object, but I think there is significant overhead in that approach. After looking for a solution, I found the following using the placement new:

```
void* memory = operator new[](sizeof(Test) * 8);  // Allocate raw memory for 8 objects
Test* arr = static_cast<Test*>(memory);  //Convert to desired type
// Construct objects using placement new

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    new (&arr[i]) Test(9);  //Assume Test has constructor Test(int)
}

// Use the initialized array

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    arr[i].~test();  // Explicitly call destructor for each object
}
operator delete[](memory);  // Deallocate memory
```

I am wondering if it is possible to deallocate the memory as the following:

```
delete[] arr;
/*instead of 
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    arr[i].~test();
}
operator delete[](memory); */
```

I tested it in VS2022 but I want to make sure that there aren't problems with the approach.

In VS debugger the code was running without problems, but I am worried about possible memory leaks or deleting more than what's already allocated.

Comment: `arr` was not returned from `new Test[size]`, so passing it to `delete[]` is undefined. (Informally, since you did not create an array, you can't destroy an array.)

Comment: OT: You may want to get familiar with algorithms such as [`std::uninitialized_fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill_n), and [`std::destroy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_n) to get cleaner code.

Comment: Why not abstract this away using some [creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)? This way you could create the objects on demand and delete them automatically.

Comment: Is your type movable? If so, I'd recommend simply using `std::vector<Test>`: `std::vector<Test> arr; arr.reserve(8); for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { arr.emplace_back(9); }`

Comment: I'm still new to STL, and in fact I was trying to recreate the vector class and that's where it all came up from

Answer (score 5):

> I am wondering if it is possible to deallocate the memory as the following:
>
> ```
> delete[] arr;
> ```

The answer is *no*.

To be able to use the `delete[]` operator you must have allocated and initialized it with the `new[]` *operator*.

Match `delete` with `new`, and `delete[]` with `new[]`. If you do an explicit call to the `operator new` or `operator new[]` functions, you must use the corresponding delete function. Anything else leads to *undefined behavior*.